# Odoo 10.0 why Mass Mailing/Campaign stops sometimes?

Tags: odoo

is it normal?
like if you check the image i am sharing, i am getting this and it is not changing anymore (seems like it is stuck). it will start sending emails after i will restart odoo service. Please advise[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnv2n.png)

Answer (score 0):

If want to send mail immediately, then set up Email queue manager. It available **Setting->Automation->Scheduled actions->Email Queue Manager**.
And also if you use any free smtp server like gmail, then gmail only provide you some limited no. of mail per day. So you can't send large no. email for mass mailing.